# ssms could not convert varchar to numeric

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table that stores multiple values but an error occurs
(show converting data type varchar to numeric).

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    Employee_iD TINYINT NOT NULL,
    Frist_Name VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    Last_Name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
    Email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Phone_number NUMERIC,
    Hire_date DATE NOT NULL,
    Job_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Salary DECIMAL(8, 2), 
    Commission_Pct DECIMAL(2, 2),
    Manager_ID TINYINT,
    Department_ID TINYINT
);

INSERT INTO Employees (Employee_iD, Frist_Name, Last_Name, Email, Phone_number, Hire_date, Job_ID, Salary, Commission_Pct, Manager_ID, Department_ID)
VALUES ('100', 'Steven', 'King', 'SKING', '5151234567', '1987-06-17', 'AD PRES', '24000.00', 'NULL', 'NULL', '90');
```

I am hoping I will get the data loaded in my table

Comment: The reason of this error are strings `'NULL'`

Comment: `Frist_name` should probably be `First_name`; datatype `decimal(2,2)` means: 2 digits total, 2 of which **after** the decimal point (so ***NO*** digits before the decimal point) - is that really what you wanted??? When inserting **numeric** values and `NULL` - you **MUST NOT** put those into single quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert the value `'NULL'` which is `varchar` in columns `Commission_Pct` and `Manager_ID` which are defined as `decimal(2,2)` and `numeric`.
You must use `NULL` instead, without the quotes:

```
insert into Employees
(Employee_iD,Frist_Name,Last_Name,Email,Phone_number,Hire_date,Job_ID,Salary,Commission_Pct,Manager_ID,Department_ID)
values
('100','Steven','King','SKING','5151234567','1987-06-17','AD PRES',24000.00,NULL,NULL,'90');
```

There are also other columns defined as number types for which you insert `varchar` values, like `Salary`. The difference is that the value `'24000.0'` you insert for `Salary` can be implicitly converted to `DECIMAL(8, 2)` so there is no error.
 
But the string literal `'NULL'` cannot be interpreted as `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the apostrophe's 'xxx' from non string values...tinyint, numeric and decimal.

Comment: I should also suggest that phone number is stored as an nvarchar so that it can accommodate a leading zero, spacing, dashes and plus symbol (+44 1604 123456)

Comment: always think hard before using `nvarchar` in stead of `varchar` . I would only use it when you really need to store values in unicode, which often is not the case.

Comment: @Guido, yes to your comment, except that we all hope our software is going to grow and be used outside of the region we live in...in which case nvarchar is the correct choice...even though it doubles your storage requirements.

Comment: not necessary. If your software is used in china, it will still work correct using varchar when they use their own database. It will only go wrong when in china they input data in a database that is also used in the US for example. Only in that case you need nvarchar

Comment: Yes, exactly my point. I think you will find that storage is cheaper than redevelopment when needs change.

Comment: maybe not when your database is on a cloud. They will be happy when your database almost doubles in size and thus also your monthly cost... And apart from that, also consider performance issues with indexes

Comment: This is why the nvarchar vs varchar debate rages...at the end of the day, there are pro's and cons to both. Choose what suits your needs today, but consider the future.